# How to find out number of unique rows within a pandas groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I know that we can use .nunique() on a groupby column to find out the unique number of elements in the column like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'], 'c2': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'c3':[1, 2, 1, 1]})

    c1 c2  c3
0  foo  A   1
1  bar  B   2
2  foo  A   1
3  foo  B   1

df.groupby('c1')['c2'].nunique()

c1
bar    1
foo    2
Name: c2, dtype: int64
```

However, now I have a groupby object that contains multiple columns, is there any way to find out the number of unique rows?

```
df.groupby('c1')['c2', 'c3'].???
```

---

Update:
So the end result I want is the number of unique rows within each group that's grouped based on the 'c1' column, such as this:

```
foo 2
bar 1
```

---

Update 2:
Here's a new test dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar'], 'c2': ['A'
, 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'], 'c3': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do this!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar'],
                   'c2': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
                   'c3': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1]})

def check_unique(df):
    return len(df.groupby(list(df.columns.values)))

print(df.groupby('c1').apply(check_unique))
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [131]: df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3']).size().rename('count').reset_index()[['c1','count']].drop_duplicates(subset=['c1'])
Out[131]:
    c1  count
0  bar      1
1  foo      2
```

**OLD answer:**

IIYC you need this:

```
In [43]: df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3']).size()
Out[43]:
c1   c2  c3
bar  B   2     1
foo  A   1     2
     B   1     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU. However, what I want is the number of unique rows within the groups such as 'bar' and 'foo', instead of sizes of all the groups...any way to do this?

Comment: can you post a desired output in your question?

Comment: I just added the result I want. So I guess I can groupby 'c1' first, then for each group, I can group by all columns again and find out the length of the group which will be the number of unique elements in the group...Problem is I don't how to do this :-)

Comment: Hmm, i tested using the new dataframe that can be found at the bottom of my post above, but it gave wrong count for 'bar', should be 2 but gave 1 for some reason, with this: df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3']).size().rename('count').reset_index()[['c1','count']].drop_duplicates(subset=['c1'])

Answer (score 0):

If need by [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) concanecated column `c2` and `c3`, the easier is use:

```
df['c'] = df.c2 + df.c3.astype(str)
print (df.groupby('c1')['c'].nunique())
c1
bar    1
foo    2
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Or `groupby` by `Series` `c` by column `df.c1`:

```
c = df.c2.astype(str) + df.c3.astype(str)
print (c.groupby([df.c1]).nunique())
c1
bar    2
foo    2
dtype: int64
```